# How to select the last record in extjs grid when I move to the last page

Tags: extjs, grid, load

Thanks you at first!
    I encountered a problem, when I load a grid and moveLast(),but I can not select the last row,here is my code:

```js
var store = this.getMyOwnStoreStore().load({
  scope : this,
  callback : function(){
    Ext.getCmp("pagingtoolbarId").moveLast();
    Ext.getCmp("gridId").getSelectionModel().select(theLastRowNumber -1);

  }
})
```

But when i run the code,I can not get the record of the last page!!!

Answer (score 2):

The select method of selectionModel actually expects record(s) - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select.

For this to work use the following - `Ext.getCmp("gridId").getSelectionModel().select(gridStore.getAt(gridStore.getCount()-1));`

Answer (score 1):

inQstvJS's answer helped me figure this out as I was placing a number in "select(1)" thinking that "select" just wanted the index of an item in the grid. Not realizing that it wants the index of the store item. Thanks

```
id = grid.config.store.data.items.length;  
grid.getSelectionModel().select(grid.store.getAt(id));
```